# Why does SQL build not validate for apparent errors, and how do we achieve automatic validations?

Tags: sql-server, msbuild

It was realized in QA with manual user testing that there was a code error, and upon investigation it was an obvious error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureA
  @A INT
AS SELECT 1
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureB
AS EXEC ProcedureA @B = 0
```

Also, manual execution of these `CREATE` statements do not throw any error.

---

Another example

```
CREATE VIEW VW_MyTestView AS
    SELECT Column1 = 0
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTestProcedure AS
    SELECT Column1
    FROM VW_MyTestView
GO
ALTER VIEW VW_MyTestView AS
    SELECT Column2 = 0
```

It is not validating dependencies when modifying objects.

---

And another appalling case are `INSERT` statements with an unequal number of columns in the `FROM` clause like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(TheOnlyColumn)
SELECT
    Column1 = ...
    ,Column2 = ...
    ,Column3 = ...
```

This issue is at least caught when altering/creating a stored procedure.

---

Another example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @MyFlag BIT = 0
AS BEGIN
    IF @MyFlag = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @MyImportantVariable DATE = GETDATE()
    END

    EXEC MyOtherProcedureThatNeedsAnImportantValue
        @MyImportantParameter = @MyImportantVariable
END
```

There are no errors, and the value `@MyImportantVariable` will be `NULL` when it gets referenced not following any declaration. I'd actually prefer an error to be thrown in this case, since debugging a surprising `NULL` value is more difficult.

---

Another example, similar to #1 that has caused me an egg on my face after surviving thousands of gated TFS builds over the past year:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @MyRequiredVariable INT--has no default
AS BEGIN
    ...
END
GO
EXEC MyProcedure--omits required parameter
```

---

Why does the MSBuild process not catch stuff like this, that is clearly invalid, and is there any way to add validation for such referential errors? I can understand the first two cases as necessary when publishing changes, because otherwise you would have a catch-22 of not being able to refresh definitions that reference each other, but this third case makes no sense to *ever* be acceptable, and the fourth case would never even compile in a language like C#.

This is defeating our gated check-in build validation process as well.

Comment: These kinds of questions are not likely to get a concrete answer unless the development team that wrote the software weighs in. If you feel it is a defect, you should submit it for consideration to the appropriate company/group.

Comment: Cannot believe that 4 people voted to close this question `Primarily Opinion based` are you kidding me?? It is a proper valid question but if you dont know the answer to it, dont just vote to close it.

Comment: I suspect it was from my use of opinionated words like "obvious" which I still firmly believe are appropriate (and a professional assertion, not just an opinion). If they are not obvious, I implore you to comment why because I am not seeing why a modern language could reasonably lack such validations (noting that building is one of the earliest steps where *egg-on-your-face* issues could be automatically detected, thus considerably minimizing costs from having to deal with definitive errors much later in the development process).

Answer (score 2):

This happened because of the [`Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx) property of SQL Server stored procedures.

If it was anything other than a stored procedure , a function , a table or view etc it would have errored out at compile time.

But SQL Server Stored Procedures are only checked for syntactical accuracy at the time of creation and the definition of the stored procedure is stored as it is.

It is only at the run-time, on very first execution the objects 
referenced by procedure are checked and if anything is missing, the procedure throws an error.

Comment: I can definitely understand why this would be important for temporary stored procedures (e.g. is mutated at runtime), but I am not aware of any real-world use case where a _permanent_ stored procedure couldn't have its references validated like a compiled language does.
If the deferred name resolution property cannot be disabled (?), perhaps a workaround would be to enable no execute and invoke every stored procedure at the end of the build? But that seems really hackish.

Comment: So there is no way to disable deferred name resolution on non-temporary objects in the build?